# Relationship between Hive and Hadoop MapReduce?

Tags: hadoop, hive, mapreduce, hdfs

**Is there any Hive internal process that connects to reduce or map tasks?**

Adding to that!

- How does Hive work in relation with MapReduce?
- How is the job getting scheduled?
- How does the query result return to the hive driver?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For HIVE there is **no process to communicate Map/Reduce tasks directly**. It's communicates (flow 6.3) with `Jobtracker`(Application Master in YARN) only for job processing related things once it got scheduled.

This image will give clear understanding about,

> 1. How HIVE uses MapReduce as execution engine?
> 2. How is the job getting scheduled?
> 3. How does the result return to the driver?

[image: Hive design]

**Edit:** suggested by dennis-jaheruddin

> Hive is typically controlled by means of HQL (Hive Query Language)
>   which is often conveniently abbreviated to Hive.

[source](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Design)

Comment: For completeness: Hive is typically controlled by means of HQL (Hive Query Language) which is often conveniently abbreviated to Hive.