# Purpose of using HBase in Hadoop instead of Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase, hdfs

In my project, we are using `Hadoop 2`, `Spark`, `Scala`. `Scala` is the programming language and `Spark` is using here for analysing. we are using `Hive` and `HBase` both. I can access all details like file etc. of `HDFS` using `Hive`.
But my confusions are -

1. **When I can able to performed all jobs using `Hive`, Then why `HBase` is required to store the data. Is it not an overhead?**
2. **What are the functionality of `HIVE` and `HBase`?**
3. **If we only used Hive, Then what should be the problem?**

Can anyone please let me know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1. When I can able to performed all jobs using `Hive`, Then why `HBASE` is required to store the data. Is it not a overhead?
> 2. What are the functionality of `Hive` and `Hbase`

`HBase` is No Sql database which stores the data in key value pair. `Hive` has integration with `Hbase`.[Hbase HIve Integration](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HBaseIntegration)

Advantage :- `Hive` queries over `HBase`. Think joins and a easy way to do aggregates and simple operations on your `Hbase` data.
`Hbase` gives you a scalable storage infrastructure that keeps data online. StumbleUpon uses `Hbase` for their live website. `Hive` is not a real-time query engine, so its data store could not be used for similar purposes. `Hive` over `HBase` gives you the benefit of both worlds.

> 3. If we only used Hive, Then what should be the problem?

If we will use `Hive` There is no problem . But in  project there so many scenarios we have to consider .

- **Performance**
- **Storage**
- **Stability of used technology**
- **Compatibility** (Hive ware house is easily accessible for most of the Tools in Hadoop)

Answer (score 5):

> When I can able to performed all jobs using Hive, Then why HBase is
>   required to store the data. Is it not an overhead?

I can't say it's overhead or not. But HBase responds to requests in real-time as its database when it comes to Hive it runs jobs on MapReduce/Spark/Tez engines.

> What are the functionality of Hive and HBase?

**Hive:**

It's a SQL-like language that gets translated into MapReduce/Spark/Tez jobs. it only runs batch processes on Hadoop. *for more check this [how Hive queries run on MapReduce engine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40510986/1592191)*

**HBase:**

It's key/value store database which runs on top of HDFS/S3(on AWS). It does real-time operations for requests.

> If we only used Hive, Then what should be the problem?

As discussed If the query needs to process in real-time then HBase is the choice over Hive.